# How to add a custom color to material-ui component?

Tags: material-ui

In some `material-ui` components, we have a prop called `color`. We can pass `'default', 'inherit', 'primary', 'accent', 'contrast'` to it. But can we pass a custom color to it? For example, I need to style a button in red. How can I do it if it's not my primary or accent color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just give the button a `style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}` and it will change the color of the button.

```
 <FlatButton label="My Colored Button" style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a custom hex value?

Comment: @THpubs Yes, just the same as the example in my answer. `style={{backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}`